# Dynamically toggle class based on div's width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, joomla3.0

So I have a container with content and two side drawer (left/right) that when open, they squeeze the content width.

```
<div class="container">
    <div">sidepanel-left</div>
    <div class="content">content</div>
    <div>sidepanel-right</div>
</div>
```

For example: when both sidepanel-left and right are close, the "content" div is 1000px width. When one sidepanel is open, the "content" div is pushed to 800px because sidepanel are 200px width. When both sidepanel are open, then the "content" div is 600px.

I would like a script that adds/removes a class ".small" dynamically to the "content" div when it's smaller/bigger than 700px.

That way, if you open or close any or both sidepanel, the "content" div will receive it's class ".small" without resizing the window or reloading the page.

I will use that class to hide/show other div inside "content" div.

I have tried this plugin (http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-resize/examples/resize/) but it won't dynamically add/remove the class. It adds the class when I open the two sidebar, but if I close one, which makes the div "content" larger than 700px, it won't remove it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    
     $(".content").resize(function() {
        if ($(".content").width() < 700 ) {
           $('.content').addClass('small');
        } else {
            $('.content').removeClass('small');
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance :)

B.

[EDIT]

website is: www.unicyclist.info 
sidepanels can be activated by clicking the [...] on the top right and left corner. 
[image: Here is an image of the ".content" div (named with the class ".es-content".]

Comment: Can you give us a code example; maybe a jsfiddle?

Comment: Why is the var there?

Comment: Oups, the var is definitely my mistake! Sorry! :s

Comment: As in, 'it is a transcription error' or, ' that was the issue in this question'? If the latter, wanna mark my answer below as correct?

Comment: You can check my website here: http://unicyclist.info/

The sidepanel can be activated by clicking the left or right [...] on the headerbar in each corner. The ".content" div is named with the class ".es-content". I will add a picture to my initial post.

Comment: So, are you trying to achieve mobile responsiveness? If so, then you should do this with CSS, not javascript.

Comment: You are getting a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'w' of undefined` error in the console. Are you sure it is implemented properly?

Comment: I am not sure any of this is implemented proprely, I have really basic PHP and JS knowledge.

Comment: I am not trying to achieve mobile responsiveness. I know I can use @media to change css based on the window's size but I want my changes to be based on the div's width. I just want to add a class to that div based on its width so it can affect child div with different css.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty sure the `var` is your mistake.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    
    $(".content").resize(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('small', ($(this).width() < 700) );    
    });
});
```

Comment: Your code is adding the class, but not removing it when closing the sidepanels. See my edited post with more info and link. Thank you very much for your time in helping me!

Answer (score 0):

**JQuery resize() is only triggered when the browser window changes!**

You can create your own function to check if the size of the div has changed:

```
contentWidth = -1;

function checkForSizeChange() {
    var $content = $('.content'),
        width = $content.width();

    if(contentWidth != width) {
        if(width < 700) {
            $content.addClass('small');
        } else {
            $content.removeClass('small');
        }       
        contentWidth = width;
    }
}

setInterval(checkForSizeChange, 100);
```

Comment: I believe that the plugin he is using, http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-resize/examples/resize/, allows resize to be on elements.

Comment: Ah I see, maybe I can leave my answer here in case someone views the question who is looking for a short code snippet that detects div size changes?